# Why does ++++x return an increment of 2 when the value of x is only incremented by 1?

Tags: evaluation, syntax, assignment

This line returns `3`:

```
x = 1; ++++x
```

[image]

However, the value of `x` after the increment is only 2.
Similarly, this line returns `5`, while the value of `x` is again only 2.

```
x = 1; ++++++++x
```

[image]

Why does it return `3` and `5` respectively in the above examples?

---

(This question is intended as a puzzle, and to encourage people to think through an opaque evaluation chain.)

Comment: I'm too sleepy to write an answer but the explanation is clear if you TracePrint, and consider the HoldAll causes evaluating to from outside to inside as we disussed in chat the other day

Comment: @Szabolcs this might be more involved than you think, but of course I don't know what you think.  I added an example you should also consider.

Comment: That's all consistent with my understanding. I wrote a short answer.

Comment: Doesn't it happen on all releases of 8?  I get exactly the same what you get in 7.  Is it possible that those who got a different result simply forgot to set a value to `x`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`TracePrint` will show you what happens:

`PreIncrement` takes it's argument `x`, evaluates it (let's call the result `result`), then evaluates `x = result+1`.  Note that `PreIncrement` has `HoldFirst`.

Now `++(++x)` evaluates `++x` first yielding `2`, then evaluates `(++x) = 2+1` resulting in an error (trying to assign to `PreIncrement`) and returning `3`.

This also explains why adding yet another layer of `PreIncrement` will increment the result again.

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here's a self-implemented `++` to make the above more clear.  The behaviour is exactly the same:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Alright, I yield.

Answer (score 3):

Using `FullForm` on the expression yields

```
++++x // FullForm
```

> ```
> PreIncrement[PreIncrement[x]]
> ```

`PreIncrement` increments the value of its argument by one, and returns the new value; notice that it has the attribute `HoldFirst`. Mathematica 8 issues a warning here that `PreIncrement` is protected and cannot be incremented, while strangely enough printing 3 nevertheless. In any case, `x` is incremented only once (by the inner `PreIncrement`), giving it a value of 2.

Comment: "while curiously enough printing 3 nevertheless" -- that's rather the point of the question, isn't it?

Comment: I'm running 8.0.4 and I get `++++x` returned unevaluated, alongside with the messages, of course.

Comment: @rcollyer oh nuts, they fixed it.

Comment: @rcollyer I'm running 8.0.4 and it evaluates (plus the mentioned warning). Odd

Comment: I get `PreIncrement[PreIncrement[x]]` when using `FullForm`, but `++++x` when not.

Comment: Entering `++++x` without assigning a value to `x` before results in two errors: Cannot increment `x`, cannot increment `++x`.

Comment: David, that appears to be why I'm not getting the same result. :P

Comment: @rcollyer Are you sure you set a value to `x` (`x=1`) before doing this?

Comment: @Szabolcs hence, my last comment to David.

Answer (score 2):

A quick test shows that assignment returns the right hand side even if the left hand side is protected:

```
Protect[a]; a=b
(*
==> b
*)
```

Now `++x` (i.e. `Preincrement[x]`) is equivalent to `x=x+1`. Indeed, this is true even for the argument evaluation:

```
++foo[Print["x"]];
```

outputs "x" twice (and gives a "recursion limit exceeded"), just like

```
foo[Print["x"]]=foo[Print["x"]]+1;
```

Therefore

```
++++x
```

is equivalent to

```
++x = ++x +1
```

where the left side is unevaluated (due to `HoldFirst`) but cannot be set (due to `Protected`), but the expression nevertheless evaluates and returns the result of `++x + 1`, which of course increments `x` once, but gives 2 more than the old value of `x`.