# Problem with function inside brackets. Bug?

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation, assignment

This code adds random digits to lists, and it works fine:

```
a = {{1}, {2}, {3}};
Do[
  j = RandomInteger[{1, Length[a]}];
  AppendTo[a[[j]], RandomInteger[9]];
  Print[a], {i, 5}];

(* {{1,7},{2},{3}}
   {{1,7},{2,2},{3}}
   {{1,7},{2,2},{3,9}}
   {{1,7},{2,2},{3,9,1}}
   {{1,7,2},{2,2},{3,9,1}}  *)
```

But if I replace the 'j' inside the [[]] with the definition j in the previous line, everything goes haywire:

```
a = {{1}, {2}, {3}};
Do[
  AppendTo[a[[RandomInteger[{1, Length[a]}]]], RandomInteger[9]];
  Print[a], {i, 5}];

(* {{1},{1,7},{3}}
   {{1},{1,7},{1,4}}
   {{1,7},{1,7},{1,4}}
   {{1,7},{1,7},{1,7,9}}
   {{1,7,9},{1,7},{1,7,9}} *)
```

Is this a bug or something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "everything goes haywire"? It's hard to tell what's wrong, given the random numbers in the code (and therefore the outputs that are never the same). Can you elaborate?

Comment: @march Initially `a = {{1}, {2}, {3}}`; after the first step of appending it's `{{1},{1,7},{3}}` - you append `7` to `{2}` and get `{1,7}`.

Comment: I believe I see the problem. `RandomInteger[{1, Length[a]}]` is evaluated *twice* in the second case. I will write a quick answer.

Comment: Answers by @Szabolcs and @march dispel the mystery. Note also that this case is a good use case for `BlockRandom`; that is, as an alternative to your first approach you could also use `Do[AppendTo[a[[BlockRandom[RandomInteger[{1, Length[a]}]]]], 
   RandomInteger[9]];
  Print[a], {i, 5}];`

Comment: @kglr  Thanks for that explanation of BlockRandom. This is a good example of where the documentation sometimes shows HOW to use a function but doesn't give examples of WHY the heck you ever would.  So now I understand what BlockRandom is for, thank you.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [(107619)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/107619/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard perhaps your answer there should include the fact that this happens with `AppendTo[]` as well as `Increment[]`.

Comment: @Feyre If this becomes closed as a duplicate I will surely do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the issue. In the second (non-working) code,

```
RandomInteger[{1, Length[a]}]
```

is evaluated *twice*, as we can see by `Trace`ing the evaluation:

```
SeedRandom[2]
a = {{1}, {2}, {3}};
Trace[AppendTo[a[[RandomInteger[{1, Length[a]}]]], RandomInteger[9]], TraceInternal -> True]
```

1. `{RandomInteger[9], 8}`
2. `AppendTo[a[[RandomInteger[{1, Length[a]}]]], 8]`
3. `{{a, {{1}, {2}, {3}}}, {{{{a, {{1}, {2}, {3}}}, Length[{{1}, {2}, {3}}], 3},  {1, 3}}, RandomInteger[{1, 3}], 3}, {{1}, {2}, {3}}[[3]], {3}}`
4. `a[[RandomInteger[{1, Length[a]}]]] = Append[{3}, 8]`
5. `{Append[{3}, 8], {3, 8}}`
6. `a[[RandomInteger[{1, Length[a]}]]] = {3, 8}`
7. `{{{{a, {{1}, {2}, {3}}}, Length[{{1}, {2}, {3}}], 3}, {1, 3}}, RandomInteger[{1, 3}], 2}`

We can see in Line 1 that `RandomInteger[9]` evaluates to 8, so we will be appending 8 to one of the lists. In Line 3, `RandomInteger[{1, 3}]` evaluates to 3, so we're going to append to `a[[3]]`. This happens on Line 5, where 8 is appended to {3} to make {3, 8}.

Now, the kicker: In Line 7, `RandomInteger[{1, Length[a]}]` is evaluated *again*, so it evaluates to a different number. In this case, it evaluates to 2, so instead of replacing `a[[3]]`, we are replacing `a[[2]]` with `{3, 8}`. Hence the output after this evaluation is

```
a
(* {{1}, {3, 8}, {3}} *)
```

---

Now, the *fix* here is to do things the way you're doing it in the first code. I would probably wrap the entire thing in a `Module` with `j` as a local variable, but it's the same process.

Comment: Ooooooh... Interesting.  So not a bug, but that second evaluation sure seems like an iffy design feature.  Thank you for your insight and the time you put into writing this up.  This was instructive and helpful.

Comment: @JerryGuern. Well, I think Szabolcs has a pretty good explanation of why the double evaluation occurs, in terms of what `AppendTo` is likely *literally* doing behind the scenes. I think that that particular "design choice" for `AppendTo` makes some amount of sense.

Answer (score 11):

No, not a bug.

Let's think about how `AppendTo` may be implemented (even though the actual implementation isn't inspectable).

```
SetAttributes[appendTo, HoldFirst]
appendTo[a_, val_] := (a = Append[a, val])
```

What happens if we evaluate the following?

```
appendTo[ a[[ RandomInteger[{1,3}] ]],  x ]
```

It simply does this:

```
a[[ RandomInteger[{1,3}] ]] = Append[a[[ RandomInteger[{1,3}] ]], x]
```

That's because `RandomInteger[...]` didn't get evaluated before substitution due to the `HoldFirst`.  Now we have two of them.  And they may evaluate to different values.  So we may get things like

```
a[[1]] = Append[ a[[3]], x ]
```

if the first random number we get is 1 and the second is 3.

I hope this makes it clear.  I have a vague feeling that the same has been asked before in a different form.

Comment: Would you kindly review the link I just added in the comments below the question, and vote to close this question as a duplicate if you feel that is appropriate?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I knew there had to be a duplicate!