# Confusing behavior when passing a variable vs. inlining a function call

Tags: variable-definitions

Newbie question here. Consider the following two functions:

```
f1[n_] := (
  q = {0, 0};
  Do[q[[RandomInteger[{1, 2}]]] += 1, n];
  Return[q]
  )

f2[n_] := (
  q = {0, 0};
  Do[k = RandomInteger[{1, 2}]; q[[k]] += 1, n];
  Return[q]
  )
```

Both seem to be doing the same thing: create a list of zeros, increment a random element $n$ times and return the list. The difference is that the first version "inlines" `RandomInteger` call into the indexing, while the second defines an intermediate variable `k`.

The function `f2` works as expected, while `f1` does not. For example, `f1` sometimes returns lists for which sum of elements is not equal to the input `n`, which seems very strange.

> In[357]:= f1[10]
>
> Out[357]= {6, 7}

Can someone point out why `f1` and `f2` are treated differently?

Comment: compare `f1[2] // Trace` and `f2[2] // Trace`

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107619/is-dangerous-for-c-programmers. (The issue with `AddTo` is the same as with `PreIncrement`.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Mathematica* is an expression rewriting language. When it evaluates:

```
q[[RandomInteger[{1, 2}]]] += 1
```

It first rewrites it as:

```
q[[RandomInteger[{1, 2}]]] = q[[RandomInteger[{1, 2}]]] + 1
```

The result is that `RandomInteger[{1, 2}]` gets rewritten **twice**, possibly as different random integers.

Answer (score 7):

The main problem is that `q[[k]] += 1` is equivalent to `q[[k]] = q[[k]] + 1`, and so [`RandomInteger`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomInteger) gets called twice. When the random number is the same (which happens half the time), then the behavior is what you expect. When the random numbers are different, then the behavior is completely different. Here is a version of your code where I add some debugging (I also removed the completely superfluous [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Return) statement):

```
f1[n_] := (
    q = {0,0};
    Do[q[[Echo@RandomInteger[{1,2}]]] += 1; Print[q], n];
    q
)
```

Here is a short example:

```
SeedRandom[3]
f1[3]
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> {0,1}
>
> 2
>
> 2
>
> {0,2}
>
> 2
>
> 1
>
> {3,2}
>
> {3, 2}

Let's see what happens. In the first iteration, we have:

```
q[[2]] = q[[1]] + 1
```

and so the result is `{0, 1}`. The second iteration does:

```
q[[2]] = q[[2]] + 1
```

and so the result is `{0, 2}`. The final iteration does:

```
q[[1]] = q[[2]] + 1
```

and so we get `{3, 2}`.